# Why are there multiple recovery keys?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

We had a user device showing as incompliant in Endpoint manager due to secure boot un-enabled.
In order to enable it, we converted the device from MBR to GPT, so we could switch it from Legacy BIOS to UEFI and then enable Secure Boot. As part of this process we had to turn BitLocker off and then back on after we completed this.

For some reason though, there are a ton of recovery keys generating, as shown in endpoint manager. I compared to other devices, and noted that other devices only have 1 recovery key and also something interesting I noted for **Drive Type** is that at some point it was generating for "**Operating System Drive**" multiple keys but now it switched the drive type to "**Fixed data drive**"

[image: recovery keys]

Why is it doing this? The device remains incompliant and cant find much information about this issue. I ran into [this post here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/983f4d44-0954-42a8-98a3-8b09222e5d7d/multiple-bitlocker-keys-are-showing-for-my-intune-managed-devices-in-azuread?forum=microsoftintuneprod)/[answer](https://twitter.com/ConfigMgrDogs/status/1108190437108383744?s=20) but I dont think it applies since we dont have windows 10 v1809, instead ***windows 10 v20H2***

***Device info:***

```
Edition Windows 10 Business
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎7/‎6/‎2020
OS build    19042.1706
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

User disk management:
[image: disk management]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>manage-bde -status
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Disk volumes that can be protected with
BitLocker Drive Encryption:
Volume \\?\Volume{e8c61f7b-eba6-11ec-b32d-7c7a918c931b}\ [System Reserved]
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 0.54 GB
    BitLocker Version:    None
    Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 0.0%
    Encryption Method:    None
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:       None Found

Volume C: []
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 237.06 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 256
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:
        TPM
        Numerical Password
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t just reimage the drive? It’s odd you require Secure Boot to be enabled and the device didn’t have it enabled, and the only way to do that, is to disable it. Does this system have multiple drives installed?

Comment: @Ramhound please see disk management screenshot I uploaded now from the user's device

Comment: You can check for and view recovery keys using the `manage-bde` command-line tool.

Comment: @DanielB see output in updated post